# Uploading images to a server with php and javascript's xml httprequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

So, I want to upload images to a server with php and javascript's xml httprequest.
I do know how to upload data like names and similar, but have no idea how to do that with images. I want to say that I don't how how to pass an image to php with javascript using xmlhttprequests.

javascript:

```
function addArticleCat() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("articles_cat_table").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
    };
    var catName = document.getElementById("article-cat-name").value;
    xhttp.open("GET", "js/ajax.php?f=articleCat&cat_name="+catName, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

php:

```
if ($_GET['f'] == 'addArticleCat')
{
    $cat_name = $_GET['cat_name'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO b_news_categories (cat_name) VALUES('$cat_name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());        
}
```

Comment: You should never send data with a GET request

Comment: look at this https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/322/how-to-convert-a-base64-image-into-a-image-file-and-upload-it-with-an-asynchronous-form-using-jquery

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: You need to convert your image to `base64` and later turn on to a byteArray for saving it in your DB.

Look at this https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/322/how-to-convert-a-base64-image-into-a-image-file-and-upload-it-with-an-asynchronous-form-using-jquery